# How can I use an ssh tunnel for debugging my flask application on GCP?

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, ssh

I am trying to test my flask application on my local machine. The flask application exists on a GCP Virtual Machine. If I am using the GCP cloud, I can run the following commands inside the cloud shell terminal:

```bash
cloudshell$ gcloud compute ssh <ProjectName> -- -L 5000:localhost:5000
server$ flask run
```

... and using GCP's `web preview`, I can see 'hello world' in my browser

However, If I follow these steps from my local computer, using the following commands:

```bash
local$  ssh jliddy@<IP> -L 5000:localhost:5000
-> (bind: Cannot assign requested address)
server$ flask run
```

...And then I connect to localhost:5000, I get no response.

I know that port 5000 is available, because If I run flask locally, I get the 'hello world' page I am expecting.

Let me know if I can give any more information!

Thanks, 
-- Jacob

Answer (score 1):

It seems that my solution was as simple as changing the SSH command from:

```
ssh jliddy@\<IP\> -L 5000:localhost:5000\
```

to:

```
ssh jliddy@\<IP\> -L :5000:localhost:5000
```

Note the extra `:` in the second command.